# string does not end with null

Tags: c++, string, function, concatenation

I'm a beginning student of C++ and i encountered a problem with the following code:

I'm trying to concatenate a 'new line' or `"\n"` to a string in a matrix of char.
So far I managed to concatenate a `" "` char but the char `"\n"` or just typing multiple `" "` won't work.

The actual sample is getting 3 strings in const value of 10 (max chars) for each of the 3 matrix's I defined-assigning values to the first two and using a function to 'change' the third and printing it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

const int LINES = 3;
const int MAXCHARS = 10; //TO DO: change to 81 for final version

void cpyAndCat(char[][MAXCHARS], char[][MAXCHARS], char[][MAXCHARS], int);
void main()
{
    char text1[LINES][MAXCHARS], text2[LINES][MAXCHARS], text3[LINES][MAXCHARS];

    cout << "Enter " << LINES << " lines into text1:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < LINES; i++) // assign the matrix of chars text1 with strings
    {
        _flushall();
        cin.getline(text1[i], MAXCHARS);
    }
    cout << "Enter " << LINES << " lines into text2: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < LINES; i++) // assign the matrix of chars text2 with strings
    {
        _flushall();
        cin.getline(text2[i], MAXCHARS);
    }
    //TO DO: call the function which will recieve text1 and text2 
    //and put blank line(line too long) or copied line from text1 and catanted line form text2.(long correct size)
    cpyAndCat(text1, text2, text3, LINES);
    cout << "============================================================\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < LINES; i++) // print third matrix of chars, prints 3 lines of either text or '\n'
    {
        _flushall();
        cout << text3[i];
        cout << endl;
    }

    system("pause");

}
void cpyAndCat(char text1[][MAXCHARS], char text2[][MAXCHARS], char text3[][MAXCHARS], int lines)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) // searches if length of string from first 2 matrix is valid
    {
        if (strlen(text1[i]) + strlen(text2[i]) < MAXCHARS) // if so, copy the first to the third and catanate the second to the third
        {
            strcpy_s(text3[i], text1[i]);
            strcat_s(text3[i], text2[i]);
        }
        else // if else (: , catanate 'new line' to the third matrix
        {
            strcat_s(text3[i], "\n"); // not working                                                                           
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the *real* code that you tried. `strcat_s(text3[i],"\n"// not working` is an obvious syntax error that, judging from the rest of your code, you probably didn't really use.

Comment: Just use `std::string`. Really, it will make everything easier and better.

Comment: excuse me but i do not understand, that is the real code i tried. and that what im trying to figure here- what should i put instead of the "\n" char.                                                            Alan Stokes-what is the function/method you mentioned, havent learned it just yet..:/

Comment: If your book told you that `void main()` is correct, it was written by someone who does not know the language. `int main()` is the correct definition.

Comment: The code you've posted simply will not compile; therefore it must not be the actual code you're using. Please update your question with the *exact* code that you're feeding to the compiler. Copy-and-paste it; don't re-type it, and don't modify it after you've pasted it.

Comment: @KeithThompson. im a student, this is how the question presented to me. im terribly sorry if it sounds rude but this code does compile as it reaches the print section in the main it give an error "string does not end with a null".

Comment: @e-Lay: This line: `strcat_s(text3[i], "\n" // not working` is a syntax error. There is no closing `)`. Do you have that *exact* line in the code you're compiling? Copy-and-paste the code *from your posted question" and try compiling it.

Comment: `system("PAUSE")` shouldn't compile either because you aren't including `windows.h`. Use the standard-compliant `std::cin.get()` instead.

Comment: @KeithThompson, i accidentally erased it, it like that-strcat_s(text3[i], "\n");                                           i understood so far that the function 'strcat' won't get the char i wish it would, but would get a string assigned with the char.             thank you.

Comment: @KeithThompson - Looks like the OP just added the `// not working` comment in the SO editor, and miskeyed. Markdown was also hiding a `);`on the next line.

Comment: @user2176127: Incorrect. The `system` function is declared in `<cstdlib>` or `<stdlib.h>`. `"PAUSE"` is just a string literal (resolved to a command name at run time). `system("PAUSE")` doesn't require `<windows.h>`.

Comment: @Roddy: Yes, I figured that was what happened. But regardless of the cause, the code in the question would not compile.

Comment: @KeithThompson You're right, my bad! He should use `std::cin.get()` anyway.

Comment: @user2176127: Why? `system("PAUSE")` behaves differently. (With a decent execution environment for running console programs, neither should be necessary.)

Comment: Well, you could easily recreate `system("PAUSE")`'s behaviour without losing standard-compliance.

Comment: @user2176127: How? The `PAUSE` command prints a prompt "Press any key to continue . . ." (easy enough) and then reads a single character without waiting for end-of-line. There's no portable way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strcat_s` and `strcpy_s` need [three parameters, not two](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d45bbxx4.ASPX). I'm suprised you have anything compiling at all.

Also, you `strcat` onto `text3` without ever initializing it. So that's probably undefined behaviour...

Comment: i didnt wish to use strcat_s but the compiler kept tell me strcat is dangerous because it deprecates something...                         what would you? i was told that the text3 must start as garbage

Comment: @e-Lay: The compiler has a bit of a point, but `std::string` is the far better solution. To concatenate two strings, you can just use `+`.

Comment: @e-Lay: You're using Microsoft's compiler, right? `strcat` is not "deprecated" a far as the C standard is concerned, and it can be used safely if you're careful. `strcat_s` is a Microsoft-specific "safer" version of `strcat`; using it may make your code safer, but it also makes it less portable. (The 2011 C standard adds `strcat_s`, among other things, as part of an *optional* bounds-checking interface; as far as I know C++ has not added it.)

Answer (score 0):

[`strcat_s`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/d45bbxx4.aspx) takes 3 arguments, you are missing the size in bytes, also, the string was never initialized.

You would want to copy into the string and afterwards, if needed, concatenate.
Don't forget to take into account the '\0' at the end of every string.

```
strcpy_s(text3[i], 2, "\n");
```